# application settings not saving

Tags: vb.net, winforms

unfortunately my settings do not get saved. please help

```
If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Form1.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
    My.Settings.mytext = My.Settings.mytext & Str(Abs(ColorDialog1.Color.ToArgb)) & ", "

End If
```

onload i load the settings back into the textbox

Comment: What kind of problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `My.Settings.Save()`

Comment: by this is called anyway when the app is closed

Answer (score 1):

I did your above code in a windows form and it worked just fine.  Are you sure it's not changing?  I had a text box set to the value on form load and it did change even though in the app.config it didn't change at all.

EDIT:

Since these are user settings, they are saved in a user.config for the user's profile in local settings\application data folder.

Comment: very interesting. so how come the app.config did not change at alll?

Comment: it's user based saving so it goes in a user.config in the local settings\application data area for your app for the profile of the logged in person.

Answer (score 1):

Each and every time you set a setting, you need to remember to Save that setting otherwise there's really no point in setting it in the first place...

Example:

// edit a setting.
My.Setting.MyName = "Jason";

// Now, save it.
My.Setting.Save();

:-)